# Is there a bug on closures embedded in a list in R?

Tags: r, functional-programming

Here is a simple example of a closure which is a function returning a function with embedded data (After http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures):

```r
fFactory <- function(letter) {
    function(Param) {
        paste("Enclosed variable:", letter, "/ function parameter:", Param)
    }
}
```

When the function is created, `letter` is used in the returned function:

```
> FUN <- fFactory("a")
> FUN("toto")
[1] "Enclosed variable: a / function parameter: toto"
```

It works because the variable `letter` is embedded in the environment of the function:

```
as.list(environment(FUN))
$letter
[1] "a"
```

If now we create functions in a list like this:

```
l <- list()
for(letter in letters) {
    l[[letter]]$FUN <- fFactory(letter)    
}
```

Normally, running the function for the item "a" must return the same result as before, but it's not the case:

```
> l[["a"]]$FUN("toto")
[1] "Enclosed variable: z / function parameter: toto"
```

Obviously because the environment embedded in the function is not the one we expected:

```
> as.list(environment(l[["a"]]$FUN))
$letter
[1] "z"
```

It returns the last closure created in the last item of the list for all closures in the list.

I suppose that I didn't misused the R language by doing so and that there is a bug in the language. Any of you can confirm that or explain me where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Force the evaluation of argument `letter` with, well, `force()`.

```
fFactory2 <- function(letter) {
  force(letter)
  function(Param) {
    paste("Enclosed variable:", letter, "/ function parameter:", Param)
  }
}

l2 <- list()
for(letter in letters) {
  l2[[letter]]$FUN <- fFactory2(letter)    
}

l2[["a"]]$FUN("toto")
l2[["b"]]$FUN("toto")
l2[["w"]]$FUN("toto")
```

Here's an explanation (After @user2554330 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69017141/8245406)):

> In R, arguments to functions aren't evaluated until first used. So the arguments to all of the functions in your list are the global variable letter, which you change in the loop as you create them, but you never evaluate until you call them. So the functions first evaluate letter at the time of the first call, and you get strange results.

Comment: In an answer that was deleted (maybe because it asked a new question as well as providing an answer to this one), @DavidDorchies wanted a solution that forced all arguments in a single line.  You can replace `force(letter)` with `as.list(environment())` to force all arguments at once.

Answer (score 2):

This is your error.  @RuiBarradas gives you the fix.  Here's an explanation:

In R, arguments to functions aren't evaluated until first used.  So the arguments to all of the functions in your list are the global variable `letter`, which you change in the loop as you create them, but you never evaluate until you call them.  So the functions first evaluate `letter` at the time of the first call, and you get strange results.

You can fix this problem in the way Rui said:  force the argument to be evaluated before you create the function.

Comment: My answer was a bit terse wasn't it? Upvote.

Comment: @ user2554330, I have proposed an inclusion of your explanation in @RuiBarradas answer to complete his answer. Thank you both of you for your clear and quick explanations.

Comment: @DavidDorchies, that's fine with me as long as Rui doesn't object.

Comment: No, I don't object. @DavidDorchies Thanks, it does make my answer more complete, like tried to say in the comment above and I have added the link to this answer to your edit.